# How to control the way Swagger generates the model/schema for a type

Tags: scala, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-play2

I was able to setup **Swagger** with **Play** and try Swagger-ui... and I must say it's really great.

Documenting the actions of my controller with `ApiOperation`, `ApiImplicitPara`, etc. was easy and it works as expected.

Nevertheless, due to my limited knowledge of Swagger, I've an issue when defining the schema for an implicit parameter of type `body`. The class I want to map to the implicit parameter looks like this:

```
@ApiModel(value "User", description = "Represents an user")
class User private(private var json: JsValue) {

  private def setValue(key: JsPath, value: JsValue) = {
    value match {
      case JsNull => json.transform(key.json.prune).map(t => json = t)
      case _ => json.transform((__.json.update(key.json.put(value)))).map(t => json = t)
    }
  }

  def asJson = json

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "User's id", dataType = "String", required = false)
  def id_= (v: Option[String]) = setValue((__ \ 'id), Json.toJson(v))
  def id = json as (__ \ 'id).readNullable[String]
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "User's email address", dataType = "String", required = true)
  def email = json as (__ \ 'email).read[String]
  def email_= (v: String) = setValue((__ \ 'email), Json.toJson(v))
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "User's firstName", dataType = "String", required = true)
  def firstName = json as (__ \ 'firstName).read[String]
  def firatName_= (v: String) = setValue((__ \ 'firstName), Json.toJson(v))
  ...
}

object User {

  def apply(
    id: Option[String],
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
  ): JsResult[User] = apply(Json.obj(
    "id" -> id,
    "email" -> email,
    "firstName" -> firstName,
    ...
  ))
}
```

The internal representation of my model classes is JSON... and then I just provide getters and setters that read/modify the internal JSON – this solution let me handle JSON very quickly and I can pass the object as-is to MongoDB.

The problem is that the model generated by Swagger for the class above is like this:

```
User {
  json(JsValue),
  id(String): User's id,
  email(String): User's email,
  firstName(String): User's first name,
  ...
}
```

How do I prevent Swagger from putting `json` in the model?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 @ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true) 
 def asJson = json
```